# SOAP UI - Split HTTP Response Header and transfer to property

Tags: soap, groovy, http-headers, soapui

I am obtaining the following response to a HTTP Request in SOAP UI

```
TTP/1.1 201 Created
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Location: /api/authorization_servers/5362c2c46362f0e7f33379e8
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

I would like to get the value of `5362c2c46362f0e7f33379e8` in the **Location** Response Header and transfer it to a Project property called "token". Can someone tell me how I am going to do that?

I am able to get the entire `/api/authorization_servers/5362c2c46362f0e7f33379e8` into a variable through Groovy script in this way:

`def headerValue = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Register Authorization Server").httpRequest.response.responseHeaders["Location"]`

I am not able to proceed any further. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have several options if I understand you right.

You could split the value and take the last element:

```
headerValue = headerValue.split( '/' )[ -1 ]
```

You could subtract the beginning of the header:

```
headerValue = headerValue - '/api/authorization_servers/'
```

Or you could use a regular expression:

```
headerValue = headerValue.find ~/[a-f0-9]+$/
```